# C Extract number from infix string

Tags: c

I am trying to extract operators and operands from a string/char array, but unable to do so.

I've tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){



char str[] = "222+333";
char *endPtr;

long int x = strtol(str,&endPtr,10);
printf("Number is %d \n" , x);


printf("Operator is %s \n" , *endPtr);

long int y = strtol(endPtr,&endPtr,10);
printf("Number is %d\n" , y);
return 0;}
```

Not sure how can I get the operator after using the strtol function.
Also are there any ways to do this without using libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, the issue with your code is the printing of the operator. `%s` is trying to print a null terminated string and requires a memory address. You are passing a character `+` which is probably ascii on your system so turns into the memory address 43

I've changed the printf statement to print a char vs a null terminated string and it works as you expect it too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[] = "222+333";
  char *endPtr;

  long int x = strtol(str, &endPtr, 10);
  printf("Number is %d \n", x);

  printf("Operator is %c \n", *endPtr);

  long int y = strtol(endPtr, &endPtr, 10);
  printf("Number is %d\n", y);
  return 0;
}
```

To answer the comment question, endPtr is not pointing at the `3` it is pointing at the `+` which is valid for strtol to read ie a positive number, when you change the sign to divide or multiply it fails (should work with minus)

What you need to do is advance endPtr by 1 char past the operator that it is point at as in the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char  str[] = "222/333";
   char *endPtr;
   char  theOperator= ' ';

   long int x = strtol(str, &endPtr, 10);
   printf("Number is %d \n", x);

   theOperator= *endPtr;
   ++endPtr;
   printf("Operator is %c \n", theOperator);

   long int y = strtol(endPtr, &endPtr, 10);
   printf("Number is %d\n", y);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pogogeh644 I've expanded the answer to include your comment question